# Неправильный вызов библиотеки CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Использую CI.
В пользовательской библиотеке, в конструкторе, подключаю еще одну библу:
    $this->CI->load->library('redispusher');

В результате чего, происходит редирект (страница не найдена).
Сам класс **redispusher** стоит в автозагрузке.

Если зайти в класс `class RedisPusher {}` и в конструкторе поставить **die()**, то он не срабатывает:

```
function __construct(){ die('d');
        $options = array(
                'namespace' => '',
                'servers'   => array(
                        array( 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 6379 )
                )
        );
        include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska.php' );
        include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska/Key.php' );
        $this->_redis = new Rediska($options);

    }
```

Если поставить **die('d');** перед Class - тоже не срабатывет.
Вопрос в том, как найти этот стек вызовов и где происходит редирект

Comment: http://xdebug.org/docs/basic

Comment: вы как-то конкретно неправильно подключаете библиотеки к CI. да и вообще делать include() в конструкторе весьма странная затея.

Comment: @eicto, я так понимаю, сам класс писал не автор


@Oleg Ponomarchuk

> В результате чего, происходит редирект 

(запятая не нжуна) Кроме вышеупомянутого xdebug и нудной расстановки точек могу посоветовать натравить расширение chrome http headers на эту страницу и посмотреть что там за редирект, может, это даст какую-то зацепку.